# Is it correct that the IEEE style looks different for bibtex and biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, ieee-style

I am using the bibtex-ieee style for my references. Everything works fine. However, I prefer to use biber. I can compile everything but my references look different. The font size is much larger than before. Is this correct? Additionally, I cannot use BSTcontrol anymore. It has no function. Is there an equivalent function for biber or style option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BibTeX style `ieeetran` provides not only the 'internal' formatting of the bibliography but also 'external' formatting, for example choice of font size for a bibliography. That belongs really in the domain of the document class not the bibliography style. As such, `biblatex-ieee` only sets up formatting which is strictly internal to the bibliography, *i.e.* that could be applied irrespective of document class.

In terms for formatting control, this is all done from the macro layer with `biblatex`. There are several options provided by the `biblatex` core plus dedicated ones in `biblatex-ieee` which cover the same ideas as the `BSTcontrol` database entry, for example the `doi` and `dashed` load-time options.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to apply the 'external' formatting from BibTeX style ieeetran to biblatex-ieee? I could adapt the font size and left margin but some bib items have different spacing between words. I couldn't find an automatic way to fix this.

Comment: @Thomas That's a separate question but is a general `biblatex` thing: it's not specific to IEEE style